# Проверка строки по регулярному выражению

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Что то не разберусь, у меня с регулярками всегда было тоскливо.
Вобщем есть строки вида:

1. 100;400
2. 1.1;400
3. 100;4.3
4. 5.3;7.9

Для целых чисел написал следующей паттерн

```
`/^(\d+);(\d+)$/`
```

Нужно расширить его для проверки на числа вида float

Comment: А что должно проверять? Не проще ли разбить строку на массив, по разделителю `';'` и обработать оба числа отдельно?

>Для целых чисел написал следующей паттерн

Вы написали не для целых, а просто для некоторых цифр, которые являются строками.

Comment: это проверка на входные данные, использую схему JSON поэтому и нужно проверить таким вот макаром, чтобы пропустить объект и работать с нам дальше.

Comment: Как-то так 

    [0-9.]

Comment: @webphp, кстати если с регулярками все тоскливо рекомендую пройти https://regex.alf.nu/, а потом http://regexcrossword.com/

По итогу будете регэкспы писать, как на родном языке )

Comment: ага, спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все-го то осталось добавить опциональную неучитываемую в результатах группу с точкой и одной или более цифрой.

Начнем с точки и циферок, точку экранируем:

```
\.\d+
```

Добавим условие опциональности (группа встречается один раз или не встречается вовсе):

```
(\.\d+)?
```

Ну и уберем ее из результатов

```
(?:\.\d+)?
```

В итоге имеем:

```
^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?);(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$
```

[Проверяем тут](http://rubular.com/r/YMpxiHIxXo).

Comment: Огромное спасибо за развернутый ответ! =)

Comment: Зачем так всё усложняете? В вопросе явно указано "проверка". Зачем нагромождать всё это скобками, да тем более не запоминающими?

Вот, вот, работает абсолютно также:

    ^\d+(\.\d+)?;\d+(\.\d+)?

И вообще вполне хватило бы выражения типа:

    [0-9.]+;[0-9.]+

т.к. автор ничего не говорит о том, что нужно обезопасить проверку от дураков, которые вводят зачения типа: 1213.;.1231

Comment: Сегодня прочерка, а завтра автор вспомнит, что ему нужен был парсинг, с защитой от дураков, разумеется. Не вижу ничего дурного в полноценном решении.

Comment: Разумеется, ваш вариант тоже вполне себе годится.

Comment: вот, вот только не нужно ссориться, горячие финские парни xD
Буду иметь ввиду два решения для данной задачи, будет уроком для меня =)

Comment: @webphp, да вроде и не думали

Comment: @webphp просто я "за" оптимизацию при написании кода. А не после =)

Answer (score 2):

```
`/^(\d+\.?\d*);(\d+\.?\d*)$/`
```

Comment: Пролезут числа вида `12.`

Comment: @Nofate, согласен. постфиксная проверка есть в вашем ответе :)